# Timing program execution

Tags: c, memory-management, benchmarking, execution-time

I have a project written in C and I would like to know if there is a simple way to profile its execution time and memory usage under Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), run your program, and then go back to procmon and use  *Tools/Process Activity Summary* to have an overview of the time and memory used by your program.

Answer (score 0):

Timing information is easy enough: create a .bat file invoking the program, output the current system time before the program starts and after it ends...something like this in pseudocode:

```
print system time
execute program
print system time
```

As for memory consumption, I would say it's a bit more involved, although definitely doable. You might try something along [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682050(VS.85).aspx) lines...